Modeling scoring functions
I'm looking for general direction on topics to explore for this problem. I think I'm not searching for the right statistical concepts and therefore coming up empty handed. Also, I'm a computer scientist, but hoping to get some expertise from the math wiz community.
I have a bunch of Observations. These observations have a fixed set of properties (let's just say {size, location, age, type}).
I want to build a function that calculates a result (score) for an observation so that I can compare Observations linearly (I want to then "choose the N highest scores").
My first inclination is to model this as a polynomial function with simple weights. I could say that 2S+L+A+T implies a 2x multiplier for the importance of size. For properties that are enums, I guess I'd just map to a discrete value that is stack ranked (e.g. location, some locations imply higher value than others). I think I would need each variable to be normalized between [0-1] as well.
The problem then becomes, in mind, trying to articulate how this function will behave.
I feel like this is a common CS/statistical problem but I'm just not keying off the right foundational concepts.
